# Not able to open Visual Studio Community installer

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio Community edition using the installer from the official site but when I download the installer and run it ,it opens and automatically closes within 2 secs. I am just not able to get my head around as to why it is not working. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Here are  the log file

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM: Commandline arguments = --env,_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\himan\Downloads\vs_community__557207469.1619805124.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\himan\Downloads
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM: C2R signature did not exist or could not be read: 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM: Parent process name = vs_community__557207469.1619805124
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM: Parent process product version = 16.9.31205.134
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM: CampaignId = 557207469.1619805124
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM: ResponseId not available in 'vs_setup_bootstrapper.config'. Trying to parse filename.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:35 AM: loading config settings: -update --update --layout -offline --offline --locale --layout --originalworkingdir --installLayoutPath --env
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: DownloadURL = https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: InstallLocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: OfflineFilePath = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: LayoutLocation = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: ExecutableArguments = /finalizeInstall install --in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_202105010040360004.json" --locale en-US --activityId "56bd55db-dd7d-4194-a911-20c87ef1ffcb" --campaign "557207469.1619805124"
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: OSVersion = Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19042.0
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: Starting to detect the existing VS and .NET...
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:5/1/2021 12:40:36 AM: Finished detecting the existing VS and .Net
```

The 2nd one

```
[5/1/2021, 0:40:35] === Logging started: 2021/05/01 00:40:35 ===
[5/1/2021, 0:40:35] Executable: C:\Users\himan\Downloads\vs_community__557207469.1619805124.exe v16.9.31205.134
[5/1/2021, 0:40:35] --- logging level: standard ---
[5/1/2021, 0:40:35] Directory 'C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Temp\32171f8d8288561c0f60c0\' has been selected for file extraction
[5/1/2021, 0:40:35] Extracting files to: C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Temp\32171f8d8288561c0f60c0\
[5/1/2021, 0:40:35] Extraction took 375 milliseconds
[5/1/2021, 0:40:35] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\himan\Downloads\vs_community__557207469.1619805124.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\himan\Downloads"'
[5/1/2021, 0:40:38] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[5/1/2021, 0:40:38] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0xc0000005
[5/1/2021, 0:40:38] === Logging stopped: 2021/05/01 00:40:38 ===
```

Comment: 0xc0000005 is instantly familiar. Sucks when the installer crashes out with an access violation.

Comment: Were you given a hash key or something you can use to test that the installer didn't get corrupted on the way down?

Comment: The logs seem to be from installation of the Community edition of Visual Studio, not from Visual Studio Code. (Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are completely unrelated products. Please only tag the relevant one.)

Comment: As described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14f82ab1-2171-47d8-b4bd-a85da2099239/cannot-install-visual-studio?forum=vssetup) "The error code ‘0xc0000005’ often means ‘access denied’, please try to temporarily disable any antivirus software and run the installer as administrator to have a try."

Comment: Make sure you're actually installing [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and not [visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)

Comment: I wasn't given a hash key and I also have no antivirus software on my system just windows defender. I can easily install Visual studio code but these errors only happen when I try to install Visual studio community version

Comment: I'm voting to close this because you need to edit the question and make it explicitly clear if your goal is (A) To install Visual Studio Code or (B) to install Visual Studio Community Edition.  They are completely different products.

Comment: Hey sorry if it was ambigious but  I am trying to install the community edition. I have also made edits in the question to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try uninstalling and deleting all previous files for VS Code and then reinstall.

Comment: I have tried that. It still doesn't work.